# Поиск букв в строке

Tags: java, строки

Пишу игрушку в которой надо угадать строку (название фильма) вводя отдельные  буквы (игра типа "Поле чудес"). Если введенная буква присутствует в строке, то она выводится на экран на своей позиции в строке, остальные буквы заменены прочерками.

Вопрос: надо ли строку преобразовывать в массив символов или есть более простой способ?

Comment: Чтобы найти символ в строке, преобразовывать строку в массив не нужно. Достаточно воспользоваться одним из перегруженных вариантов  метода [indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-int-).

Comment: Indexof В данном случае неудобно юзать если одна и та же буква встречается больше 1 раза.

Comment: indexOf здесь вообще не нужен, все решается методом replace

Comment: Лучше создать коллекцию, заполнить ее символами из строки и осуществлять поиск в этой коллекции.

Comment: При такой расплывчатой постановке вопроса на него ответить невозможно. "Надо ли"? -- для чего именно? Тут многое зависит от того, как у вас решены другие связанные с этим вопросы. А в общем виде - решений может быть миллион. Попробуйте сами придумать несколько способов и посмотрите сами, какой из них проще.

Comment: @AntonSorokin -- "строка(String) и есть массив символов" -- в каком это смысле? Вы ничего не путаете? Вы уверены, что разобрались в вопросе?

Comment: @m.vokhm да уж, странно что я так считал

Answer (score 1):

реализация на `replace`

```
String word = "винЕгред";
String alphabet = "абвгдеёжзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя";
String currWord;
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

do {
    char letter = reader.readLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0);
    alphabet = alphabet.replace(letter, '*');
    currWord = word;
    for (char ch : alphabet.toCharArray()){
        currWord = currWord.replace(ch, '-');
        currWord = currWord.replace(Character.toUpperCase(ch), '-');
    }
    System.out.println(currWord);
} while (currWord.contains("-"));
reader.close();
System.out.println("вы выиграли!!!");
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.